# iOS Previously Bonded BLE Devices

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've searched everywhere for the answer to this and have yet to find a definitive answer...  Please help...

I have created an app that connects and bonds to a BLE device which requires a pin.  The pin is pragmatically created and displayed to the user before the iOS bluetooth bonding dialog is triggered.  So far, so good.  If the user correctly enters the pin into the bonding dialog the phone and the BLE device are now bonded and everyone is happy.

Now the user closes the app and terminates the bluetooth connection.

When the app starts up again and the BLE device is discovered, is there any way to know that the bonding has already taken place?  Basically, I don't want to re-display a pin to the user if the device has already bonded.

I'm currently saving the identifier of the BLE device and calling RetrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers to see if the device has been connected before.  This works but if the user goes to the bluetooth listing and selects "Forget this device", RetrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers still returns ther peripheral.  I've tried restarting the phone, uninstalling and reinstalling the app.  Nothing seems to make iOS forget that at some point in the past, that identifier was connected...

Help!

Answer (score 3):

iOS has no API whatsoever for pairing or bonding. iOS will only prompt a pairing dialog upon request from the other device or when it reads a characteristic that requires security. Your app won't even know that the pairing dialog is being shown, when pairing is complete, or when/if the current link is encrypted.

If the device is already bonded and the LTK that iOS has stored during a previous pairing process can be used (the slave also has it), then the link will automatically be encrypted and therefore no new pairing dialog will be shown.

The list about previously connected devices has nothing to do with bonded devices. It's just a list of previously known devices.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up concepts a bit. Bonding essentially means "having the same Long Term Key".

So if you have two devices, and you want them to open up an encrypted connection, both devices simply check if they have a key associated with the corresponding device, and try to use this key to encrypt the messages.

This is why a device can't really check if the bond still exists. Each device can check if its own key still exists, but how would it know if the other device still has the key? As soon as one side has forgotten the key, the bond is lost.

I don't have much experience with iOS, but I assume their should be a function to get the stored Long Term Keys to check if there is an LTK associated with a Bluetooth address. Alternatively, it should be possible to 
use external storage so that instead of the stack doing it for you, you can define a file where all keys are stored, and provide the stack with the key when needed. (At least, this works with other implementations.) In this case, you could directly look in the file to check if the devices have been bonded.

Note that entering the pin corresponds to the process of "pairing". The successful conduction of this procedure and the subsequent encryption of the connection does not prove that the devices are bonded. After disconnection, the pairing information is lost and the devices need to pair again - except if you have stored the key, which makes the pair a bond.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem in my app, where if the user selected "Forget this device" from the settings then my app wouldn't know.

You can use `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID])` to check if your device is connected to the OS. If yes then proceed with your other functions, else show PIN again(or whatever you want).

`retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` will return the device if it was connected to your OS previously.

I am doing this in my app. Hope this helps.